# Why is this happening?(Weird thing occuring with django models)

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is really weird and to me makes no sense (at least at the moment).

I have the following code in models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete
from django.db.models import Max,Count
from django.apps import apps

# Create your models here.
class Player(models.Model):
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    current_level_no = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    no_of_moves = models.IntegerField(null=True)    

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Players'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.player_name

class PlayerStats(models.Model):
    player_name = models.ForeignKey(to=Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    level_no = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    moves = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Players Stats'

# It works!
TotalLevels = 25
MaxCurrentLevels = PlayerStats.objects.aggregate(max_levels=Max('level_no'))['max_levels']
playerscount = PlayerStats.objects.aggregate(count_players=Count('player_name', distinct=True))['count_players']
print(playerscount)


def create_player(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        new_username=instance.username
        Player.objects.create(player_name=new_username, current_level_no=None, no_of_moves=None)

def delete_player(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    deleted_username=instance.username
    Player.objects.filter(player_name=deleted_username).delete()

def create_player_stat(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    for x in range(1, TotalLevels+1):
        PlayerStats.objects.create(player_name=instance, level_no=x, moves=None)


post_save.connect(create_player, sender=User)
post_delete.connect(delete_player, sender=User)

post_save.connect(create_player_stat, sender=Player)
```

I have no idea why querying for Max value of the Level field of the model PlayerStats gives me no errors but Count of distinct Player names field of the same model give me an error that Models aren't loaded yet. It should give me the same error if the Model hasn't loaded yet when querying for max value but it doesn't. If I comment out the lines for the query for Player names field, it all works fine. This just doesn't make any sense and I am having a hard time figuring out what is causing this and how to fix this!

Can someone please help me out here?

As always, I greatly appreciate your answers!

Comment: Have you tried `Count('player_name__player_name', distinct=True)` or `Count('player_name__id', distinct=True)` ?

Comment: Just tried them, gave me the same error again.

Comment: Models aren't ready yet, you can't run queries on the top level of models.py